# Is there a way to access the Wasteland survival guide straight from the game?

Tags: wasteland

I have only recently started playing the original Wasteland (sadly, it wasn't really available around here at the time it was published), and I have noticed that sometimes it refers to the manual. I believe it is called the "Wasteland survival guide".

Can it be accessed straight from the game? What I mean is, is it bundled with it? Or do I have to get it somewhere?

Comment: From the title, I was expecting a Fallout 3 question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those parts of the game that specifically reference the manual or paragraph book, you are indeed intended to reference the real, paper books that came with the game. (I believe that this was done due to space constraints on the game disks, but that's just my speculation.)

For people who purchased the original game, this was obviously no big deal, but for people who wish to revisit the game today without access to the original manuals, obviously, an alternative is required.

Luckily, the [Desert Ranger Outpost](http://wasteland.protozoic.com/) fansite has PDF and text versions of both the manual and the paragraph book available for free download.

Comment: You could also get this game via the [Ultimate RPG Archives](http://www.amazon.com/Ultimate-RPG-Archives-Pc/dp/B00001QEPC/) and they included an electronic version of the manual rather than a physical one (still external to the game). Mainly I'm just mentioning this so no one is like "Zomg only pirates would use this!"

Comment: referencing the game manual was the beginning of the process that we call DRM today. Back when adventure games fit on a floppy, creators would install gates in their game that you would be unable/unlikely to pass without access to a game manual.